# writing global listener

Tags: java, swing, listener

I want the active window (i.e JFrame ot JDialog) to receive specific keyEvent so that whereever the focusing this keyevent is handling by the window such as ALT+F4 if you press
it wherever the focusing the active window will close,I try to override postprocesskeyEvent but it doesn't work fine

Answer (score 1):

You can add a global event listener to you application using the addAWTEventListener() method in java.awt.Toolkit.

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#addAWTEventListener%28java.awt.event.AWTEventListener,%20long%29

You will need to choose which type of events you want to receive with the event mask when you add the listener.

For example:

```
// Then on startup register.
AWTEventListener myGlobalKeyListener = new MyGlobalKeyListener();

Toolkey.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(myGlobalKeyListener, AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
```

If you are trying to stop windows from shutting down your application when the user presses ALT-F4 then an event handler will not help you.  I belive the operating system handles this by sending SIGTERM to the application.  Java does not receive the KeyEvent for this.

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach for intercepting KeyStrokes when using Swing is to use [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/). Although as mentioned earlier this still won't work for Alt+F4.

If you are trying to prevent Alt+F4 from closing the window, then you need to use the setDefaltCloseOperation(...) method to do nothing. [Closing an Application](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/) gives more information on this approach.